# How to update all resources that were created with kubernetes manifest?

Tags: kubernetes

I use a kubernetes manifest file to deploy my code. My manifest typically has a number of things like Deployment, Service, Ingress, etc.. How can I perform a type of "rollout" or "restart" of everything that was applied with my manifest?

I know I can update my deployment say by running

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment name>
```

but what if I need to update all resources like ingress/service? Can it all be done together?

Comment: You can use `kubectl apply` to reflect changes in a manifest file to the resources.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar) has already suggested in his comment, you can simply use:

```
kubectl apply -f your-manifest.yaml
```

and it will apply all the changes you made in your manifest file to the resources, which are already deployed.

However note that running:

```
kubectl rollout restart -f your-manifest.yaml
```

makes not much sense as this file contains definitions of resources such as `Services` to which `kubectl rollout restart` cannot be applied. In consequence you'll see the following error:

```
$ kubectl rollout restart -f deployment-and-service.yaml
deployment.apps/my-nginx restarted
error: services "my-nginx" restarting is not supported
```

So as you can see it is perfectly possible to run `kubectl rollout restart` against a file that contains definitions of both resources that support this operation and those which do not support it.

Running `kubectl apply` instead will result in update of all the resources which definition has changed in your manifest:

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment-and-service.yaml
deployment.apps/my-nginx configured
service/my-nginx configured
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to store your manifests, e.g. `Deployment`, `Service` and `Ingress` in a directory, e.g. `<your-directory>`

Then use `kubectl apply` to "apply" those files to Kubernetes, e.g.:

```
kubectl apply -f <directory>/
```

See more on [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/).

When your `Deployment` is updated this way, your pods will be replaced with the new version during a rolling deployment (you can configure to use another deployment strategy).

Comment: okay - this makes sense. How do I configure a 'rolling' deployment when I apply `kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yaml` ?

Comment: that is the default behavior